# How To Check If An Object Property Has Been Set In A User Supplied Parameter?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have a method that takes an object as a parameter and all expected properties are required else I want to throw an error. Whats the best practice for doing this. Can it be done easily with Underscore's `_.map` or something similar?

By "required" I mean anything but `null` and `undefined`.

Comment: What a vague question!!

Comment: This is pretty easy to do even in just a few lines of plain JS. What have you tried? _"all expected properties are required"_ - What does "required" mean in this case? Anything but `undefined`, or do you want to exclude values like `null` and empty strings too?

Comment: @nnnnnn I agree about it's easy to find a solution yourself, but I disagree about asking "what does "required" mean?". If we talk about method arguments, what can it be? :)

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer - I did give some examples of defined values that nevertheless may not count as "required" in some cases. (E.g., `null`.)

Comment: @nnnnnn You know that in a generic meaning, "required" means that the whole argument must given when calling the whole method. Thus, `undefined` would mean "not given".

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer - Except the calling code may have explicitly set some of the required properties to the _value_ `undefined`, as compared to simply not defining them. (But yes, you're right.)

Comment: @nnnnnn Yeah, that's why my answer tries to address the problem using an intersection and I check for the length of the result. Do you expect `X` arguments? If interesection returns other result than `X`, the contract is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use [`_.intersection`](http://underscorejs.org/#intersection) and `Object.keys`:

```
function yourFunc(args) {
    if(_.intersection(["name", "secondName", "age"], Object.keys(args)).length != 3) {
        throw Error("Check your arguments: something is missing!");
    }
}
```

Note that this kind of check will work if arguments aren't instantited from a prototype. [From Mozilla Development network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

> The Object.keys() method returns an array of a given object's own
>   enumerable properties, in the same order as that provided by a
>   for...in loop (the difference being that a for-in loop enumerates
>   properties in the prototype chain as well).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it without a library, using just the standard JavaScript [array `.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method:

```
function yourFunction(params) {
   if (params == null || typeof params != "object") {
      throw "Missing parameters - 'params' must be an object";
   } else if (["rp1", "rp2", "etc"].some(function(p) { return !(p in params); })) {
      throw "Missing parameter";
   }

   // if we got this far the parameters were all supplied
};
```

...Where the values in the array (`"rp1"`, etc) are the names of the required parameters.

If you want to support pre-IE9 then you could use whatever Underscore's equivalent method is.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all properties using `Object.keys(your_object)`. This will produce an array of object keys.

Answer (score 0):

```
var requiredKeys = [....];

function isCorrectObject(obj, testForTruthy) {
  return _(requiredKeys).every(function(key) {
    return obj[key] || (!testForTruthy && _(obj).has(key));
  });
}
```